# Não consigo debugar módulo importado em projeto no Visual Studio Community 2019

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, debug

Estou usando a versão 16.7.5 do Visual Studio Community 2019 em que estou implementando pela primeira vez um `pyproj` (Python versão 3.8.3) em um ambiente virtual `env`.

Instalei a biblioteca `elasticsearch-dsl` no ambiente virtual e rodei a aplicação web com sucesso, porém ao tentar aplicar um "*breakpoint*" em qualquer linha no arquivo `C:\Users\User\source\repos\MeuProjeto\MeuProjeto\env\Lib\site-packages\elasticsearch_dsl\utils.py` eu encontro o seguinte alerta:

```
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Breakpoint in file excluded by filters.
Note: may be excluded because of "justMyCode" option (default == true).Try setting "justMyCode": false in the debug configuration (e.g., launch.json).


Location: utils.py, line 68...
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquisei algumas soluções para isso e encontrei em "Debug > Options > Debugging > General" a caixa "*Enable Just My Code*" habilitada; no entanto, mesmo ao desmarcá-la, não houve qualquer mudança.

Existe mais algo que possa ser feito para eu tentar resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrei a opção "*Enable debugging of the Python standard library*" dentro de "Tools > Options > Python > Debugging" e, juntamente com "*Enable Just My Code*" em "Tools > Options > Debugging > General", o "*breakpoint*" funciona agora.

Answer (score 1):

Para você conseguir `debuggar` seu *código*, abra o `launch.json` para criar o arquivo, clique com o botão direito em um arquivo executável no *Solution Explorer* e escolha *Debug and Launch Settings*, escolha a opção que melhor corresponda ao seu projeto, abra ele e adicione essa linha `json`: `"justMyCode": false`.

[Link da resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58430028/visual-studio-code-breakpoint-set-to-grey-color-not-working-errormay-be-exclu) (para vs code)

[Link da documentação da microsoft(en)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/launch-vs-schema-reference-cpp?view=vs-2019) (visual studio 2019)

Comment: Estou precisando usar o [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/pt-br/vs/community/), acredito que nele eu não tenha acesso ao `launch.json`, mas posso estar enganado.

Comment: Poxa, me desculpe já encontrei o link e como criar o arquivo correto. vou editar a resposta